# Why using push or any array method modifies the original array but assigning it to something else doesn't?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I don't understand why assigning the array to a new value doesn't affect the new array. 
I know that "push" modifies the original array, splice also, and filter or slice doesn't, this is not my question. my question is that why assigning doesn't.
i have looked through old questions answers saying it is passed by reference but again if it is passed by reference then changing it's value should affect the reference also.

```
const modify = (someArray) => {
    // modified my array
    someArray.push(1)
    // modified my original array
    someArray[0] = 'A'

    // didn't modify my array and I want to know why.
    someArray = ['whatever']
}
let myArray = ['a', 'b']
modify(myArray)
console.log(myArray) //  ["A", "b", 1]
```

Comment: I two objects(Arrays) refer to same object in memory then it means that whenever we will **modify** one of them the other will also be modified. It doesn't mean when we will **reassign** one of them to a new value the second the will change.

Comment: so we can't re-assign?

Comment: `someArray` and `myArray` are two different variables which refer to same object in memory. When you **modify** `someArray` `myArray` is also modified. But when you reassign it `someArray = ['whatever']`. It will then not refer to the variable `myArray`.

Comment: A variable is a container for a value. Some values can be modified directly (objects are mutable), others cannot (strings are immutable). Assigning to a variable always "exchanges" the existing value with the new value. Note that `someArray[0] = 'A'` *doesn't* assign a value to the *variable*. It *reads* the variable, "extracting" the value it contains and mutates that value (changing the first element of the array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've described this to beginners many times, I've found that it's best to think of Objects in Javascript as being passed and assigned as a pointer (as in the way pointers work in C/C++).  So, when you do this:

```
let a = [1,2,3];
let b = a;
```

You now have two variables that each have a pointer to the same `[1,2,3]` array.  I find it works best to think about the array existing on its own and you now have two variables that each point at that array.  When you assign `b = a`, it doesn't make a copy of the data, it just points `b` at the same data that `a` was pointing at.

If you modify that array with something like `a.push(4)` or assigning like `a[0] = 9`, then the one and only one array that both `a` and `b` point to has been modified.   So, whether you access that array from `a` or from `b`, you will see the change because both variables point at the same physical array object.

But, if you reassign some other array to `b` like this:

```
b = [9,8,7];
```

You've just taken a new array and put a pointer to it in `b`.  The other variable `a` still points to the same original array that is used to.  It hasn't been changed in any way.

When you pass an array as an argument like you are doing in your `modify()` function, the function argument in the function is just like the `b` variable in the above example.  It's just another variable that points at the same array.  If you modify the array itself, then both variables will point at the same modified array.  But, if you reassign the argument variable to now point at some other array, only that variable is affected.

Comment: *"passed and assigned by pointer"* sounds dangerously similar to "pass and assigned by reference"*, which is wrong. Also the fact that objects are reference-type values doesn't seem to be *that* relevant to how variables work?

Comment: @FelixKling -  For anyone who knows how pointers work in C/C++, the description matches what happens in Javascript exactly.  I use this model to explain it over and over again, exactly because there's no use of the word "reference" anywhere in my  answer which often confuses people.  In C/C++, If `a` and `b` both have a pointer to the same array, then any modification of the memory of the array through either one modifies what the other is also pointing to.  But, if you assign something different to `b`, it doesn't affect what `a` is pointing to at all.  That's how JS works.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. Maybe it's the word "by" that bothers me. idk :)

Comment: @FelixKling - OK, I removed "by" from my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript (and Java or C#) everything is by default passed by **value**!

The important is to know, what the value is. This line `let myArray = ['a', 'b']` creates new array in memory and put the reference to it into `myArray`. Now, the value of `myArray` is the reference to the memory where `['a', 'b']` reside.

When you pass it to `modify` function, the value - which is the reference - is **copied** from `myArray` to `someArray`. It means `someArray` can access the same memory segment of the same array, therefore change the values inside that array, but you cannot change the value of `myArray` (which is the reference to that array) from `someArray`.

Comment: I don't find that first sentence very useful for beginners because they don't know what "by value" means for an object like an array.  What is the "value" of an array? 
Is the whole object passed somehow?  Is a copy passed?  Is a pointer to the object passed?  So, you're major sentence in the answer doesn't really explain anything and leaves one confused.  It's best to use terms in the description that are clearly understood by beginners.  Later on, you try to explain what the value is which is better.

Answer (score 1):

`['a', 'b']` is an array. `myArray` is a variable that *refers* to that array. `someArray` is a variable local to `modify` function that will take the value of `myArray` (i.e. the *reference* to your array; so both `myArray` and `someArray` refer to the same array). As you noted, `someArray.push(1)` and `someArray[0] = 'A'` both modify the array referred to by `someArray`. `someArray = ["whatever"]` will change the *reference* of `someArray` to the new array `['whatever']`, but `myArray` still refers to the old array. At the end of the function, `someArray` variable disappears (and `['whatever']` is forgotten, since nothing refers to it any more).

There is no way in JavaScript to change the reference of the variable passed into a function (as e.g. C++ can); you can only manipulate what received reference points to.